# CentOS: bash: grep: command not found

Tags: bash, centos

I have CentOS release 6.3

I'm trying to use `grep` in a script and I get `bash: grep: command not found`.

Any ideas how to fix this?

A few months ago it was working properly.

Comment: Most likely, you have messed up with your `PATH` variable in script (does grep work in interactive terminal?), or did a nasty `rm` by mistake...

Comment: @anishsane I'm not the only user of the machine so I don't know. I found the problem right know. What can I do at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Locate your grep installation path. Most likely it's either `/bin/grep` or `/usr/bin/grep` .
2. `echo "export PATH=$PATH:/<path_to_grep>" >> ~/.bash_profile` . Note that ~/.bash_profile here means your bash startup file. The one that gets sourced on bash shell startup.

In case if you do not have grep for whatever reason or you just can't `find / -iname "*grep*"`- you can download and install it: [gnu FTP](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grep/). Any other reliable source is fine too. Then use steps 1 and 2 to add your grep directory to system path variable.

Comment: In `/usr/bit/` I do not have `grep` but `pgrep`, `zgrep` etc. In `bin` I have nothing.

Comment: You can run `which grep` from the command line to locate grep

Comment: @edi9999 Running `which grep` I get the result `/usr/bin/which: no grep in (/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)`

Comment: @edi9999 well obviously he can't. `which` looks at system path, isn't it? `man which`: `

DESCRIPTION
       Which takes one or more arguments. For each of its arguments it prints to stdout the full path of the executables that would have been executed when this argument had been entered at the shell prompt. It does this by searching for an executable or script in the directories
       listed in the environment variable PATH using the same algorithm as bash(1).`